# Is it possible to use an Android device as a second monitor?

Tags: screen-sharing

Sort of like this [iPad app](http://gizmodo.com/5508816/review-idisplay-turns-your-ipad-into-a-second-monitor).  Is there any way to extend your desktop onto your phone or tablet?  Not looking for VNC solutions.

Comment: I guess I should clarify: I don't want it to just VNC to another running machine, but to essentially use it as a new monitor. Comparable desktop app would be MaxiVista: http://maxivista.com (which does have an iPad app)

Comment: Could be possible, one might need to write a virtual driver for the desktop to interface with the android device and extend it as a extended monitor.. (not VNC)

Comment: All the apps below seem to just stream a portion of your desktop to the tablet. I want one that is recognised as a monitor within Windows. :(

Answer (score 12):

[iDisplay](http://www.shapeservices.com/en/products/details.php?product=idisplay&platform=android) is now available for Android.

There's a [review](http://androidcommunity.com/idisplay-for-android-turns-your-smartphone-or-tablet-into-second-display-for-computers-20110225/) on androidcommunity.com

US$4.99 in [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idisplay.virtualscreen).

Answer (score 4):

Not to my knowledge.  Both of those solutions you've listed appear to use VNC as the service.

Answer (score 1):

Early this year, arrived for Android:

[Air Display](http://avatron.com/apps/air-display) by [Avatron Software](http://avatron.com/) available for 3,79€ in [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avatron.airdisplay).

*Android 2.3.3 and up.*

Comment: That's now £6.20, and apparently doesn't work with Win8.