# Can I connect my Android mini PC to my Laptop as a monitor ? How?

Tags: screen, screen-sharing

I am buying a new Android Mini PC : http://uae.souq.com/ae-en/mk802-iv-rk3188-quad-core-cortex-a9-android-wifi-mini-pc-4995376/i/

How can I connect my Android Mini PC to my Laptop ? My Laptop only has a VGA Port.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: "... as a monitor"?

Comment: ya as a monitor. mean to say, people install it with a tv but I want to run it with my laptop is it possible ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use an Android device as a second monitor?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1922/is-it-possible-to-use-an-android-device-as-a-second-monitor)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. Similar, sure, but I think there are enough differences here for them to be separate questions.

Comment: @Aditya: What kind of output does the Android mini PC have? It looks like HDMI. If so, all you'd need is an HDMI-to-VGA converter.

Comment: Does not make sense! an output of video signals from Android Mini PC to your laptop (which is also output as well!)

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. You could install a VNC server, which would let you use a VNC client on your laptop to connect to the "mini PC" over Wi-Fi, and use the laptop's keyboard, mouse, and screen to control the "mini PC", but there are two *caveats*. First, you'd need to be able to use the mini PC directly (with a TV or monitor) to be able to install and set up the VNC server; second, you'll probably find that using VNC is not as smooth as using it directly, especially for video-intensive applications like video calling and gaming. Some games may not work at all.

To use the device properly, you'll need a monitor or TV with an HDMI input, or a monitor or TV with some other input (such as DVI) with an adaptor. You can also buy adaptors that have an HDMI input and connect to a PC with USB to make the PC act as a monitor, but they're relatively expensive. Either way, you'll need extra hardware to use this "mini PC".

Comment: I have a CRT 1024 x 768 Resolution Monitor with VGA Cable.

Comment: will that VGA work with the Mini-PC ?

Comment: Maybe. I've had mixed results with HDMI-to-VGA adaptors and Android tablets. Some tablets support it, some don't.