# Can I connect my Android Mini PC to my VGA Monitor through Adapter?

Tags: hdmi, external-display, android-mini-pc

I am buying a new [Android Mini PC](http://uae.souq.com/ae-en/mk802-iv-rk3188-quad-core-cortex-a9-android-wifi-mini-pc-4995376/i/). It has HDMI Output but I want to connect it to my VGA Monitor.

So, Can I use this [HDMI Male to VGA Female Video Converter Adapter](http://www.shopclues.com/hdmi-male-to-vga-female-video-converter-adapter-cable-cord-with-builtin-chipset.html) to connect the VGA cable of my Monitor and use HDMI to HDMI Joiner Connector to join the main adapter cable and the Mini PC?

Will this work? Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might get a better response to this question if you accept an answer on your other related question http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46295/12442

Comment: please give me some response..........  Can i connect through this ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work. however i can see that this will have lag and will not be sutiable if your going to be playing games and some heavy HD Movies. you'll just get the bare minimum quality. I Would recommend [http://www.amazon.com/Sabrent-DA-HDVG-Converter-Adapter-INCLUDED/dp/B006FYPT60](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006FYPT60)

Ofcourse if you only need the bare minimum of surfing the web, email, photos, videos, music. i would go with http://www.geekbuying.com/item/Measy--H2V-1080P-HDMI--to-VGA--convertor-cable-for-Android-TV-Box---TV-Stick---MINI-PC-314924.html
as it has audio output also. :) Hope this helps